# ps command not working properly?

Tags: debian, command-line, ps

I am using a Debian Virtual Box with the Bash shell and I am trying to use the ps command with the -c switch to find an ID of a process by searching its name. This is what I write:

```
ps -c processname
```

It then tell me:

> error: unsupported option (BSD syntax)

This is the URL for the website that told me to use the syntax I am currently using: [Understanding the kill command, and how to terminate processes in linux](http://bencane.com/2014/04/01/understanding-the-kill-command-and-how-to-terminate-processes-in-linux/)

Any help?

Comment: From the linked page, `-C` is not `-c`, and `pkill` would likely be a better option to kill by process name.

Comment: @thrig I see now, so it's just down to me not reading things carefully enough XD. Oh well now I have two methods of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this syntax instead.

```
ps -A | grep processName
```

If your results include the process grep, remove it with:

```
ps -A | grep processName | grep -v grep
```

In my experience most linux programs work the same (ps) but there are differences that will always creep up.

Check YOUR current version with the manual pages for the correct syntax for your installation.

```
man ps
```

btw: Check the man page for grep to make it not case sensitive.

```
man grep
```

Comment: When doing a ps | grep name, you have to exclude the grep process, as it matches, as in `ps -A | grep process | grep -v grep'  .  pgrep would work better here.

Comment: or use something like `ps -A | grep 'processnam[e]'` to make grep not match itself

Comment: This is a bad idea. `ps … | grep …` is highly unreliable, in particular it's prone to matching other processes where the pattern appears as part of the command line (that's the reason for the `grep -v grep` kludge, but that kludge only solves one common instance of the problem).

Comment: "grep -v grep" That's a new one.

Answer (score 1):

That blog post said to use the `-C` flag, not the `-c` flag. You replaced the uppercase C by a lowercase C, that won't work. Options are case-sensitive. To avoid such transcription problems, copy-paste.

This being said, parsing the output of `ps -C` isn't such a good idea. There's a specialized program for that: [`pgrep`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pgrep.1.html). Use `pgrep -f processname` to see what processes are running the specified command. See the manual for other useful options. When you've determined exactly what processes you want to kill, replace `pgrep` by `pkill`: `pkill` matches processes exactly like `pgrep` (it's the same code, down to being the same binary), but kills them instead of displaying information about them.